# ¿Se puede exportar los datos de una función que retorna un json a excel?

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

¿Hay forma de exportar datos de una función que retorna un Json a Excel?

Esta es mi función.

```
public ActionResult GetInventarioJson() 
{
    var inventario = GetInventario();
    return Json(inventario, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

que me retorna un Json, y me gustaría volverlo un Excel. muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Porsupuesto que es posible, te recomiendo que mires la librería [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) que es gratuita, y te será útil, de todos modos, tu pregunta en este momento es muy amplia, por lo que posiblemente no recibas respuestas, te recomiendo que estudies el tema, y, con alguna duda más puntual, crees una nueva pregunta, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

alli no estas obteniendo un `json` sino que lo devuelves serializado de esa forma al cliente que invoca al `action` del `controller`

Lo que debes serializar es la clase `inventario` retornando el excel como respuesta al cliente

[ClosedXML MVC Example: Export to Excel using ClosedXML in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ClosedXML-MVC-Example-Export-to-Excel-using-ClosedXML-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Pudes usar una libreria como ser `ClosedXml` que se bada en `open xml` para generar el excel y enviarlo para la descarga, pero no tiene nada que ver con el json porque tu tienes los datos en la entidad para generalo a partir de este

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult Export()
{
    var inventario = GetInventario();

    foreach (var item in inventario)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item.Prop1, item.Prop2, item.Prop3);
    }

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(stream);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Grid.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```

iteras la entidad y la vuelcas como row usando la libreria que luego envia el archivo en el response como `FileResult`